# How to define compatible logs

Tags: open-telemetry

I have the chance to influence the log format of a logging solution we are about to set up for an existing backend system. It is not open-telemetry based and may never be, but at the moment I can still make suggestions and would like to make sure the logs are written in a compatible format. Is there some kind of overview or definition I can use as a base? Some kind of list of mandatory fields the need to be filled?

Comment: for anyone with a similar problem, I was pointed to the data model: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/master/specification/logs/data-model.md

Answer (score 1):

I see you found the data model (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/master/specification/logs/data-model.md) in the specification - keep in mind, logging support for OpenTelemetry is currently not stable and so this may change. Generally, I suspect that if you use something like the Elastic Common Schema (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/master/ecs-log.html) then you should be broadly compatible going forward.